# Error: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Session expired or invalid

Tags: lightning-web-components, error, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I have an error when I try to uploud the code from VSCode in Salesforce organization.
The error is this : Error: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Session expired or invalid
I have a lightning web component and I want to upload in Salesforce but doesn't work

Comment: Can you try deleting the alias associated with org and try to rewrite the alias?

Comment: I solved @Vinay . 
I updated the sfdx extions and I restarted the VSCode and also the computer 
After this is functional .
Thanks for suggestion :)